How to change Label and Placeholder from Lightning-input-field which is a standard lightning component?
I have this lightning record edit form here, so now the label and the placeholder are coming directly from the record. But I want to change them according to my requirements. So how shall I change the label and placeholder here?
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" onsuccess={handleSuccess}
   <lightning-input-field field-name={nameField}> </lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>  

